# Detect creating of branches or bookmarks in HG

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

Is it possible to detect if a commit creates a new bookmark or branch via hooks in .hgrc?

I've tried to see if I can find out using hg log, but it just shows on what branch/bookmark the commit has been created: http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html

There don't seem to be hooks for it: http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html

It would make sense I suppose that there isn't a hook for it, because it is also not possible to make a commit which is 'just' the creation of the branch indicating branches/bookmarks only exists when added to a specific commit.

I figured I could check hg branches and hg bookmarks before and after each commit and determine which are removed and added, but is there a cleaner way for detecting branch/bookmark adds/removes?

Answer (score 2):

The `pushkey` and `prepushkey` hooks can detect the addition, deletion, and moves of bookmarks.

In hgrc:

```
[hooks]
prepushkey=echo %HG_NAMESPACE% %HG_KEY% %HG_OLD% %HG_NEW%\n >> out.txt
```

`HG_NAMESPACE` will contain "bookmark" and `HG_KEY` will contain the name of the bookmark.

`HG_OLD` will contain the hash of the commit the bookmark was before the operation. It won't be set if the bookmark is being created.

`HG_NEW` will contain the hash of the commit the bookmark will be after the operation. It won't be set if the bookmark is being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

1. Bookmarks

   - Bookmarks-handling **does not** require commit
   - Bookmark can be created|modified for *any* changeset in history, not only for current
   - Bookmark(s) can appear as result of data-exchange (pull|push), not local user's actions
   - Only part of all possible cases can be covered by hook
2. Branches

   - Changing branch always reflected in commit
   - Branch in changeset may differ from parent's branch not only as result of `hg branch` (see "merge branches" and "mergesets") - and I haven't nice and easy and ready to use solution for this case
3. Common notes

   - You can use standard `precommit` hook (executed before commit and can enable|disable commit) for testing different conditions in commit or or `pretxncommit`
   - Mercurial template-engine has keywords for branch and bookmark for using in `hg log -T`
   - In pretxncommit hook commit already exist, but not finalized - it means you can manipulate with commit's data using `-r tip` and tip's parent in any Mercurial command

Dirty skeleton for hook's body

`hg log -T "{KEYWORD}\n" -r "tip + tip^" | ....`

where KEYWORD may be `branch` or `bookmarks`. Result of log is two-strings output, which can be identical of different (not sure for bookmark, **TBT!!**), which you have to compare (as you want and can)

**PS:** Idea inspired by [EnsureCommitPolicy Wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EnsureCommitPolicy) and [Mercurial pre commit hook topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162384/mercurial-pre-commit-hook) here

Comment: Please update a link for ensureCommitPolicy to: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EnsureCommitPolicy